# Should [tag:methods] be a synonym of [tag:technique]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tag [methods](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/methods) does not have a wiki summary, but (based on the name and the first portion of the four questions so tagged) it seems likely it should be a synonym for [technique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) (which tag is used by 82 questions). [literary-tools](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literary-tools) (2 questions) *might* also be a synonym, but it might be addressing a specific subset of [technique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) (one of the two questions is also tagged with [technique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique)).

If they are not synonyms, someone who knows the difference should create wiki summaries.

Comment: And then there's [tag:tropes], which *should* be different but I'm not sure our usage is (2 questions).  Yes, please, let's either clarify and deconflict or, if we can't, synonomize some of these.

Comment: @MonicaCellio [tag:readers] (5 questions) and [tag:audience] (5 questions) might also be candidates for making synonyms. [tag:organization] *might* be a candidate for *splitting*--work/time management, organization of materials, organization of the final result. [tag:planning] may have a similar issue with multiple contexts. Without wiki summaries proper tagging is more difficult.

Comment: [tag:medium] (7 questions) may also be a candidate for splitting--writing/editing medium (possibly a useful subset of [tag:tools], like [tag:software]) (5 questions) and reading medium (2 questions). [tag:structure] might also need distinguishing from [tag:organization].

Comment: related: http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/320/vaguely-defined-tags, http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/230/technique-tag

Comment: "organization **in** the final result" would have been more clear, e.g., how topics should be ordered in technical writing. Chapter break questions probably fit better under [tag:structure], but ordering of subplots might fit under an 'document-organization'/'story-organization'. However, such might be less useful categories.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO [methods](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/methods), [literary-tools](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literary-tools), and [technique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) are all very iffy as tags. It's not clear what they signify - since pretty much any solution for any problem involves a method or a technique of some sort. See ["Technique" tag](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/technique-tag) for a previous discussion of the [technique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) tag.

I *definitely* don't want *more* tags like that, so let's clean [methods](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/methods) and [literary-tools](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literary-tools) into [technique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) for the moment. I'd rather abolish those tags than keep them on as synonyms, although I might be persuaded regarding [literary-tools](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literary-tools) as a synonym.

And if we can find a good solution for [technique](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique), then more power to us.

Comment: Making [tag:technique] a synonym of 'literary-technique' *might* discourage the use of the tag for things like methods of improving as a writer. I am not certain how specific **X** needs to be in "How can I avoid **X** style defect?" to be a [tag:technique] question. You indicated "purple prose" is too general. Complicating matters, question with a *specific* problem may be *answered* by giving literary techniques applicable to the class of problems. 'literary-technique' is a very broad category and might not be a very good search tool or interest group identifier.

Comment: Maybe someone could develop more extensive guidelines for using tags (tagging questions, searching for related questions, and following subjects of interest/expertise). :-) Such guidelines would probably not be heavily used (unlike "How do I ask a good question?"), but might be helpful for a minority of users (e.g., those with a need for rules--and not just those with Autism Spectrum Disorder [I probably fit into this category]).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton: The guideline that I've learned for good tagging is "tags whose meaning/use is self-evident." Anything complex or needing qualifications gets messed up. Another good one is "Who would be likely to subscribe to a feed of this tag's questions?". If the answer is either "nobody" or "everybody," it's not a good tag.

Comment: [tag:literary-tools] and [tag:methods] are now synonyms of [tag:technique]. The tag wikis have been synced automatically by the system.